# Class specific method as parameter

Tags: c#, generics, methods, delegates, windows-runtime

The main goal for me is to try understand how C# works.

I would like to do something like this :

```
static class MagicalClass
{
    public static List<T>   DoMagic<T>(List<T> sourceList, METHODPOINTER methodOfT)
    {
        return (list.OrderBy(obj => obj.methodOfT())).ToList();
    }
}
```

I can afford to do things like adding `List<T>   DoMagic<T>(List<T> sourceList, METHODPOINTER methodOfT) where T : SomeInterface` if my main objective(as described upthere) cannot be reached otherwise.

I need to replace `METHODPOINTER` by somthing like `Func<T>` but specific to a class

For instance:

```
class SomeClass
{
    private static int id = 0;
    private int currId = 0;
    SomeClass() { currId = id++; }
    public int doStuff() { return (currId); }
    public int doOtherStuff() { return (currId + id); }
}


class AnotherClass
{
    String proceedLogic()
    {
        List<SomeClass>  aList = new List<SomeClass>();
        aList.Add(new SomeClass());
        aList.Add(new SomeClass());
        var sortedList = MagicalClass.DoMagic<SomeClass>(aList, SomeClass.doStuff); // this is my goal
        List<SomeClass> sameSortedList = aList.OrderBy(x => x.doStuff()).ToList(); // would be the same thing
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible and C# can evaluate that, and even deduct the `<SomeClass>` part.
I suppose i just need to know what is the syntax and what are involved system classes.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried making the method static?

Comment: As far as i've experienced Func<...> cannot restrict it's instances to a specific class scope/methods,  I could hardcode everything but that's not my goal.

Answer (score 1):

`Func<T>` is actually a series of generic classes with a number of arguments.

The easiest way to think about `Func<T>` is as follows:

- `Func<TResult>` is a method with no parameters and a return type of
  `TResult`.
- `Func<T, TResult>` is a method with 1 parameter of type T and a
  return type of `TResult`.
- `Func<T,V,TResult>` is a method with 2 parameters of type T and V and
  a return type of `TResult`.

So in actual fact, you can pass any method pointer so long as it's signature is a well-defined delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, in the meantime as far as i've experienced Func<...> Does not allow me to restrict it's instances to a specific class scope

Comment: Then define a delegate for use only with the class. But seeing as it's a specific interface implementation, why bother passing the method anyway - you know the interface - just call the method directly?

Comment: Im really interested into defining a delegate for use only with the class but it seems i dont know the syntax to make it restricted. Somthing like `public delegate void SomeDelegate()` did not work for me. Is it a deal about where you declare it ? And as said previously i would like to avoid going through the interface solution and i really would like to avoid hardcoding the calls.

Answer (score 0):

By using T and the generic parameter TProp, the method can infer both the list type and the return type of the function used for the order by.

OrderBy expects a `Func<SomeClass,???>` to sort on.  TProp provides the ??? type.

I also included a doStaticStuff method, so that you could see how this works if you have a method that already matches the expected signature.

```
static class MagicalClass
{
    public static List<T> DoMagic<T, TProp>(List<T> sourceList, Func<T, TProp> methodOfT)
    {
        return (sourceList.OrderBy(methodOfT)).ToList();
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    private static int id = 0;
    private int currId = 0;
    public SomeClass() { currId = id++; }
    public int doStuff() { return (currId); }
    public int doOtherStuff() { return (currId + id); }
}

public static int doStaticStuff(SomeClass item)
{
    return item.doOtherStuff();
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public void proceedLogic()
    {
        List<SomeClass> aList = new List<SomeClass>();
        aList.Add(new SomeClass());
        aList.Add(new SomeClass());

        var sortedList1 = MagicalClass.DoMagic(aList, x => x.doStuff()); // pass in a Func<SomeClass,int> for OrderBy
        List<SomeClass> sameSortedList = aList.OrderBy(x => x.doStuff()).ToList(); // would be the same thing

        var sortedList2 = MagicalClass.DoMagic(aList, doStaticStuff); // pass in a function that matches the expected signature
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment about expectations of OrderBy(). That said you're hitting the point i wanted to avoid; and doing so, i also see that i have not been clear enough. The consequences of being able to set up the "concept" i want, would make impossible the use of any other method outside the "SomeClass" scope; and `public static int doStaticStuff(SomeClass item)` is outside the scope.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to accomplish that at compile time.  I am not suggesting that this is a great idea, but you could accept a parameter of type `Expression<Func<T,TProp>>` and throw an exception if it referenced a method that was not in your class (if the expression is allowed, you would .Compile() and then pass that result to your OrderBy).